# How to swap values between two columns of a tab delimited txt file in place

Tags: python

I was attempting to use a tab-delimited txt file and found that there were some errors where values in two specific columns were swapped, which forced my program to shut down.

The file has 9 columns total and columns 3 and 4 are sometimes swapped. I am attempting to write a python program that will swap the values in column 3 and 4 when column 3 > column 4. So far this is the code that I have, but I don't understand how to change the file (or write the changes) once I've set column 3 and column 4 to their new values.

```
with open('pythonTest.rtf') as x:
for line in x:
    columns=line.split()
    if len(columns)==9:
        x=columns[3]
        y=columns[4]
        if columns[4]>columns[3]:
            columns[3]=y
            columns[4]=x
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
Evan McMahon

Comment: Your code seems fine. Can you give us more specific example of your error?

Comment: PS To make your code more efficient I would suggest to set the values of variables x and y only when you want to swap them.

Comment: i'm not sure how to edit 'pythonTest.rtf' with the new values for columns[3] and columns[4].

Comment: To swap column 3 and 4 you have to use index 2 and 3!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
contents = []
with open('pythonTest.rtf') as x:
    for line in x:
        columns=line.split('\t')
        if len(columns) == 9 and columns[4]>columns[3]:
            columns[4],columns[3] = columns[3],columns[4]
        contents.append('\t'.join(columns))
with open('pythonTest.rtf', 'w') as y:
    for line in contents:
        y.write(line)
```

Or if you are fine with creating a new file, you don't have to store it in memory. You could also overwrite the first one with the new one:

```
import os
with open('pythonTest.rtf') as x, open('pythonTest.rtf.tmp', 'w') as y:
    for line in x:
        columns=line.split('\t')
        if len(columns) == 9 and columns[4]>columns[3]:
            columns[4],columns[3] = columns[3],columns[4]
        y.write('\t'.join(columns))
os.remove('pythonTest.rtf')
os.rename('pythonTest.rtf.tmp', 'pythonTest.rtf')
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to not rewrite the whole file but just replace the changed lines?

Comment: Usually you cannot just replace lines of text files, because they are stored on the disk consecutively. Changing a line to a shorter or a longer one wouldn't be possible. In this case, the changed lines happen to be of the same length, but using this as an optimisation is not simple,  these things are done in database engines, not in text processor scripts